# Getting Rspec error no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer with Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, rspec, mongoid

I'm tying to test my Rails app with Rspec, but I'm getting a `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer` error without any apparent reason. Based on the traceback I get I think the problem is related to Mongo/Mongoid, however, I can't figure out what it is exactly. The code runs perfectly in production. The error happens only when testing.

Brief look at the model without the other methods:

```
class Card
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :front, type: String
  field :back, type: String
  field :level, type: Integer, default: 1
  field :review_date, type: DateTime, default: DateTime.now

  has_many :card_statistic, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :topic
  belongs_to :user

  validates :front, :back, :level, presence: true
  validates :topic, presence: { is: true, message: "must belong to a topic." }
  validates :user, presence: { is: true, message: "must belong to a user." }
  validates :level, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
end
```

One function in the model that triggers the error:

```
def self.reset(card)
    card.update(level: 1)
end
```

The test code:

```
it "puts the given card in level 1" do
    card = create(:card)
    Card.correct card
    card.reload
    Card.correct card
    card.reload
    expect(card.level).to eq(3)
    card.reset
    card.reload
    expect(card.level).to eq(1)
  end
```

Then, the traceback of the error I get:

```
1) Card puts the given card in level 1
     Failure/Error: Card.reset card
     TypeError:
       no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/server_selector.rb:56:in `[]'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/server_selector.rb:56:in `get'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/client.rb:170:in `read_preference'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/collection/view/readable.rb:318:in `default_read'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/collection/view/readable.rb:251:in `read'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/collection/view/iterable.rb:38:in `each'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c61547d5ed15/lib/mongoid/query_cache.rb:207:in `each'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c61547d5ed15/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:230:in `first'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c61547d5ed15/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:230:in `block (2 levels) in first'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c61547d5ed15/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:562:in `with_sorting'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c61547d5ed15/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:229:in `block in first'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c61547d5ed15/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:474:in `try_cache'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c61547d5ed15/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:228:in `first'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c61547d5ed15/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:20:in `first'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c61547d5ed15/lib/mongoid/relations/builders/referenced/in.rb:20:in `build'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c61547d5ed15/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:43:in `create_relation'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c61547d5ed15/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:26:in `__build__'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c61547d5ed15/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in get_relation'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c61547d5ed15/lib/mongoid/threaded/lifecycle.rb:130:in `_loading'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c61547d5ed15/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:100:in `block in get_relation'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c61547d5ed15/lib/mongoid/threaded/lifecycle.rb:89:in `_building'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c61547d5ed15/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:99:in `get_relation'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c61547d5ed15/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:187:in `block in getter'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c61547d5ed15/lib/mongoid/validatable.rb:79:in `read_attribute_for_validation'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/validator.rb:149:in `block in validate'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/validator.rb:148:in `each'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/validator.rb:148:in `validate'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:450:in `public_send'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:450:in `block in make_lambda'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:189:in `call'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:189:in `block in simple'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:190:in `call'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:190:in `block in simple'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:190:in `call'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:190:in `block in simple'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_validate_callbacks'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/validations.rb:395:in `run_validations!'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:113:in `block in run_validations!'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:113:in `run_validations!'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/validations.rb:334:in `valid?'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c61547d5ed15/lib/mongoid/validatable.rb:97:in `valid?'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/validations.rb:371:in `invalid?'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c61547d5ed15/lib/mongoid/persistable/updatable.rb:114:in `prepare_update'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c61547d5ed15/lib/mongoid/persistable/updatable.rb:139:in `update_document'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c61547d5ed15/lib/mongoid/persistable/savable.rb:25:in `save'
     # /home/huesitos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c61547d5ed15/lib/mongoid/persistable/updatable.rb:52:in `update'
     # ./app/models/card.rb:57:in `reset'
     # ./spec/models/card_spec.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The error is also triggered when testing the controllers. Even doing a `get :index` throws the error. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What does `Card` look like?

Comment: This is a link to the file in the repo:
https://github.com/huesitos/aplus/blob/dev/app/models/card.rb

Comment: Your `Card` has a `reset` *instance* method but you're calling `Call.reset` (i.e. the `reset` *class* method). Is that the problem? Don't you mean to say `card.reset` where you say `Card.reset card`?

Comment: Sorry for that, I fixed it and it's still throwing the same error.

Comment: Is it something in the validations? The stack trace suggests that it might be.

Comment: Well, even if I remove the validations it doesn't work.

Comment: Hey, someone helped me figure out the problem. It seems the version of Mongoid that I was using had some issues. Thanks for the effort, though :).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there where some issues with the very last builds of Mongoid and I was pulling the code directly from the repo without specifying a stable version. So the solution was to either downgrade the version to 4.0 or use the 5.0 beta build explicitly.

Either

`gem 'mongoid', '~> 5.0.0.beta', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'`

or

`gem 'mongoid', '~> 4'`

instead of

`gem 'mongoid', '~> 5', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'`